# Error in .fun(piece, ...) : argument "by" is missing, with no default - plyr package

Tags: r, plyr

I'm practicing R with dataframe InsectSprays (in R base), using plyr package:

```
ddply(InsectSprays,.(spray), summarize, sum = sum(count))

Error in .fun(piece, ...) : argument "by" is missing, with no default
```

I don't understand what this error mean, the tutorial did the exact the same command and has the output like this:

```
    spray    sum
1    A       174
2    B       184
3    C        25
```

and also I wanna create a new variable(still error):

```
spraysum <- ddply(InsectSprays,.(spray), summarize, sum = ave(count,FUN = sum)) 
Error in .fun(piece, ...) : argument "by" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Perhaps you have the `dplyr` package loaded at the same time?

Comment: umm but I didn't load dplyr

Comment: Then try `summarise` (with s not z) instead of `summarize` as [described here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/505).

Comment: @neilfws   it works for the first command, but the last one shows 'Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column sum must be length 1 (a summary value), not 12'

Comment: Second command works fine on my machine without error. Not really related to your problem, but I'd suggest learning the `dplyr` package (and perhaps also `purrr`). They have, in a sense, superseded `plyr` and are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

#cargar la librerias

```
library(plyr,dplyr)
ddply(InsectSprays,.(spray), summarize  ,sum=sum(count))
```

Result:

```
  spray sum
    1     A 174
    2     B 184
    3     C  25
    4     D  59
    5     E  42
    6     F 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `summarise` instead of `summarize`.

The following function just works fine.

```
ddply(InsectSprays,.(spray), summarise, sum = sum(count))
```